# drop down menu from database in zendframework 2 layout

Tags: layout, zend-framework2

layout.phtml code:

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="<?php echo $this->url('project') ?>">Java</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="<?php echo $this->url('project') ?>">android</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="<?php echo $this->url('project') ?>">Dot Net</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="<?php echo $this->url('project') ?>">Zend Framework</a></li>
            </ul>
```

but i want to convert into loop here.

Module.php code:

```
 class Module
        {
              public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
                $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
                $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
                $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

// this is for session


     $this->initSession(array(
                            'remember_me_seconds' => 180,
                            'use_cookies' => true,
                            'cookie_httponly' => true,
                                        ));
        // this code is not working(to get the values from db for menu list)
                $service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserService');
            $result = $service->getmenulist();
                $this->layout()->myVariable = $result;
            }

    //other code
        }
```

This is my current menu in layout, but i want make the drop down list from database. i don't know how to pass the value to layout from module.php. anyone help me to solve this issue. Is there any other way to execute it. In module.php, i am trying to get list of menu names and passing that to layout.

Comment: Learn about view helpers and dependency injection ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for retrieving the UserService doesn't belong in the onBootstrap method as it will be executed every time your app is run, regardless of whether or not you actually access that module.  This code may belong in a custom viewhelper, as @Sam suggested, which could be used to inject your menu into the layout.

If you're planning on additional functionality around the menu, for example toggling items based on an ACL, then you're approach might involve a custom Navigation container and/or a Listener to fetch and populate your menu.

Unfortunately, your question is more of a design issue and likely just an absence of a full understanding of the some basic ZF2 concepts than an actual problem with a particular piece of code. As such, you're not going to get too many responses from the community. You probably just need to review the ZF2 docs and tutorials and come back when you're having a specific problem with implementing those concepts.

- [ZF2 Navigation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.navigation.intro.html)
- [ZF2 View Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.navigation.view.helpers.html)
- [ZF2 Module Class Best Practices](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.module-manager.best-practices.html)